# Find a closed formula for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^4{x^{n-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

[Editor: Find a closed formula for?]

$$1 + 2^4x + 3^4x^2 + 4^4x^3 + \dots+n^4{x^{n-1}}+\dots$$

I think Vn method should be applied but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: The image is unnecessary. Even unformatted text is better than an image link, if the meaning is clear. Links can go away, images can't be read by screen readers, and images won't show up in searches for a formula.

Comment: The original image is of an infinite series, however the body is about a finite sum. Can you clarify which is intended?

Comment: @B.Mehta my bad, i fixed it.

Comment: Is the last term supposed to be $5^5$?

Comment: Sart from $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}$ (for $|x|<1$). Differentiate and multiply by $x$, 4 times. This must be a duplicate but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: @jjagmath last term? its an infinite series... if I misunderstood please correct me

Comment: @shivanshtiwari You did a typo in your last edit (you wrote $1 + 2^4x + 3^4x^2 + 4^4x^3 + 5^{\color{red}5}x^4 ...$), I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

just follow Anne Bauval's comment:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac1{1-x} \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nx^{n-1} = \frac1{(1-x)^2} \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nx^{n} = \frac x{(1-x)^2} \implies\\ \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2x^{n-1} = \frac {x+1}{(1-x)^3} \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2x^{n} = x \cdot\frac {x+1}{(1-x)^3} \implies \\ \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^3x^{n-1} = \frac {x^2+4x+1}{(1-x)^3} \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^3x^{n} =  x \cdot \frac {x^2+4x+1}{(1-x)^3} \implies \\ \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^4x^{n-1} = \boxed{\frac {x^3+11x^2+11x+1}{(1-x)^4} } = \frac {(x+1)(x^2+10x+1)}{(1-x)^4} $$